# Rails: Exclude certain assets from being precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want is really simple - I want all assets except a particular css file (that references image assets and thus needs to go through the asset pipeline) to be precompiled.  How do I exclude that css file from being precompiled?

Comment: Why don't you just put it in your `public/assets`?

Comment: Because sass processing doesn't happen to those files, and I can't figure out how to reference them anyway?

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple possible answers depending on what you want. I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

If it's in app/assets, you really need anything in there to go through the asset pipeline to be *available*. In production, you need to precompile all your assets in that are part of the asset pipeline -- and need to re-precompile in production mode whenever they change.

If the asset name doesn't have a `scss` or `sass` suffix, it won't go through the scss/sass compiler, although it'll still go through the asset pipeline for fingerprinting in filename, gzipping, etc.

If you really don't want an asset to go through the asset pipeline *at all*, then you can't really put it in `app/assets`.  You have to put it in `public` instead.  Then it gets confusing how to generate a URL to it, the best way is to use `public_path + "/subdir/foo.css"`.

But I'm not sure that's what you're asking. If you have an asset file that references image paths, normally you *do* need that to through the asset pipeline, absolutely!  Because it's the asset pipeline that will fill out the URLs properly for those image assets. You'll want to use the Rails asset_path helper in the asset file to generate the URL to an image. You can put an `.erb` on the end of the file, and then use ERB codes `<%= asset_path('my_asset.css') %> in it it. Or if it's sass,`asset_path` might be built into rails sass already, I forget.

I don't fully understand what problem you are having exactly, but I think what you are asking for may not actually be what you need.  Have you checked out the Rails Asset Pipeline guide? It's pretty decent. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you actually want a file precompiled separately from the other files?

If so you just need to add it to the `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` array. Look in `config/initializers/assets.rb` for a commented line as an example.